# how assign a matrix to a variable? Can the variable be a matrix variable?

Tags: matlab

I was trying to use  for loop to assign some matrix to some variables. But I could not realize it. I probably know where is my mistake, but I don't know whether there is a way to overcome it

---

```
N = 10;

for i = 1:1:N

    P(i) = [x(i)^2   x(i)*y(i);  
        x(i)*y(i)   y(i)^2];
end 

K = blkdiag(P);
```

---

I want to assign a matrix to P(i), then use those P(i) to create a block diagonal matrix. 
But it seems that I can't do this. Is there any other methods to create such block diagonal matrix?

Answer (score 5):

You can use a cell array for this:

```
for i = 1:10
    P{i} = [x(i)^2   x(i)*y(i);  
            x(i)*y(i)   y(i)^2];
end
K = blkdiag(P{:});
```